# env variables docker-compose

Tags: docker-compose, environment-variables

I would like to pass environment variables to this command inside my docker-compose.yml, how to do that? I guess the problem is in quotes. How to solve it?

```
 web:
build: .
env_file:
  - .env.dev
command: >
  sh -c "sleep 1 && python manage.py collectstatic --no-input --clear && \
  python manage.py migrate --noinput && \
  python manage.py createsuperuserwithpassword --username \
  ${DJANGO_SUPERUSER_USERNAME} --password admin --email admin@example.org \ --preserve && gunicorn job_filter_app.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000"
```

Comment: Try to put everything in " ' ".                sh -c "'"sleep 1 && python manage.py collectstatic --no-input --clear && \
  python manage.py migrate --noinput && \
  python manage.py createsuperuserwithpassword --username \
  ${DJANGO_SUPERUSER_USERNAME} --password admin --email admin@example.org \ --preserve && gunicorn job_filter_app.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000"'"

Comment: Unfortunately, your method did not work, but I found a solution in agony, maybe it will be useful to someone: 
    build: .
    env_file:
      - .env.dev
    entrypoint: ["/bin/sh","-c"]
    command:
    -  |
        python manage.py collectstatic --no-input --clear
        python manage.py migrate --noinput
        python manage.py createsuperuserwithpassword --username $${DJANGO_SUPERUSER_USERNAME} --password $${DJANGO_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD} --email $${DJANGO_SUPERUSER_EMAIL} --preserve
        gunicorn job_filter_app.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000

Answer (score 0):

It's work:

```
 build: .
  env_file:
  - .env.dev
 entrypoint: ["/bin/sh","-c"]
 command:
 -  |
    python manage.py collectstatic --no-input --clear
    python manage.py migrate --noinput
    python manage.py createsuperuserwithpassword --username 
    $${DJANGO_SUPERUSER_USERNAME} --password 
    $${DJANGO_SUPERUSER_PASSWORD} --email $${DJANGO_SUPERUSER_EMAIL} ...etc
```